# Matplotlib: Iteratively producing TeX symbols in the title and label

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, latex

I have a program which generates a bunch of plots whose titles/labels I would like to be symbols in TeX format. I know how to do this for an individual plot in matplotlib, e.g.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0,2,30)
y = np.exp(x)

plt.figure()
plt.title('Plot of ' + r'$\alpha(t)$')
plt.plot(x,y, label = r'$\alpha(t)$')
plt.legend()
```

which produces

[image]

So far so good. But now what I'm stuck on is how to do this iteratively given a list of TeX expressions. For example, I tried:

```
vars_list = ['alpha','beta','gamma','delta','epsilon']

for var in vars_list:
   plt.figure()
   plt.title('Plot of ' + r'$var$')
   plt.plot(x,y, label = r'$var$')
   plt.legend()
```

But instead of TeX symbols being produced it just writes 'var' for the title and labels. It seems that `var` is being interpreted literally, instead of as the string it refers to. Is there a way to make this work?

(My motivation for doing this is that the number of plots produced and the symbols used depend upon user inputs, so an ad hoc approach of making each plot individually won't work.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you pass the string `'var'` not the variable `var`. Do you mean:

```
vars_list = ['\\alpha','\\beta','C','D']
for var in vars_list:
   plt.figure()
   plt.title('Plot of ' + rf'${var}$')
   plt.plot(x,y, label = rf'${var}$')
   plt.legend()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Yes, exactly what I was looking for! Thank you!!

Comment: A quick follow up question: What about if ```vars_list``` contains elements with and without a backslash? e.g. ```vars_list = ['alpha','beta','C','D']```? I tried your code but it didn't work 'C' and 'D'.

Comment: Then you should do `vars_list = ['\\alpha','\\beta','C','D']` and remove the backslash in the `title` and `plot` commands. Answer updated.